# Java11 migration/ JavaFX - source errors

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

I have managed to set the environment for Java 11.01 and JavaFX and run my application, but I have several exceptions related to path issues. I'm using from graphics the `com.sun.glass.ui` and the exception tells:

```
cannot access class com.sun.glass.ui.Window (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.glass.ui to unnamed module
```

It is a unmodular project.

Should I create my JRE using jmods or?

Comment: Try `--add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=ALL-UNNAMED`.

Comment: @Jai still got WARNING: package com.sun.glass.ui.Window not in javafx.graphics

Comment: Can you post your VM options and the stacktrace you get?